# Викторина на handlebars,

Tags: javascript

```js
(function($, Handlebars) {
    
    var Quiz = {
        currentIndex: 0,
        currentScore: 0,

        handleQuestion: function(event) {
        
            var questions = event.data.questions;
            var correctAnswer = questions[Quiz.currentIndex].corect_answer;
            var userInput = $("input[name = {{../form_name}}]:checked").val();

            if (parseInt(userInput, 10) === corect_answer) {
                Quiz.currentScore += 1;
            }
            Quiz.currentIndex += 1;
        },

        renderFinalScore: function(finalScoreTemplate, questions) {
            var template = Handlebars.compile($(finalScoreTemplate).html());
            var context = {
                totalScore:      Quiz.currentScore,
                questionsLength: questions.length   
            };

            $(Quiz.config.quizEl).html(template(context));
        }
    };

    request.done(function(questions) {
        $(".sendbtn").on("click", function score(){
                var context = {
                totalScore:      Quiz.currentScore,
                questionsLength: questions.length   
            };

            $(Quiz.config.quizEl).html(template(context));
                         }
)});
})(jQuery, Handlebars);
```

```html
<!--The Question Template-->
   <section class="header">
    <div class="header__tittle">
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p>You’ve been selected in Saint Petersburg’s Apple Giveaway—win a Series 2 Apple Watch by answering these trivia questions!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="header__button">
        <button class="sendbtn">Start<img src="assets/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="quiz_content">
    {{#each quizContent}}
    <div class="quiz_item">
        <div class="quiz_question">
            {{this.question}}
        </div>

        <div class="quiz_answers">
            {{#each answer}}
            <label class="quiz_radiobtn" for="{{../form_name}}{{@index}}">
              <input type="radio" name = "{{../form_name}}" value = {{@index}} id ="{{../form_name}}{{@index}}">
              <span class="radio-indicator"></span>
              {{this.answer_1}}
            </label><br/> {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}

    <div class="quiz_btn">
        <button class="sendbtn"><span>SEND</span><img src="assets/arroww.png" alt=""></button>
    </div>
</section>


<!--The Score Template-->
  <script id="quiz_result" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each quizScore}}
            <h1>{{this.score_title}}</h1>
            <div class="score">
                <span class="score_your">{{ totalScore }}</span> of {{ questionsLength }}
            </div>
            <p>{{this.score_description}}</p>
        {{/each}}
        </div>
        <div class="header__button">
            <button class = "sendbtn">Get iphone<img src="assets/arroww.png" alt=""></button>

  </script>
```

Есть викторина, сделаная с помощью шаблонизатора Handlebats.js.Выводится 3 input(вопросы). Нужно создать скрипт, что бы он проверял значения input radio, и виводил результат уже на новой странице.

Comment: А мне не нужно. Тем более, на handlebars. Код-то где?

Comment: Извиняюсь за грубость, я имел ввиду что мне нужно)